# Special cases of modulo operator

Tags: numerical-methods

I included a function (a%b + b) % b in some old cold and remember concluding that this was due to some special cases of a%b that I needed to be careful about.  a and b are c ints and % is the c modulo operator.  Now I am having trouble seeing where these two expressions ever differ.  Are they completely equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical long division demands that the remainder is zero or positive, `a=q*b+r` with `0 <= r < b`.

In the computer implementations of this operation it is possible that `a%b` is negative. Thus adding `b` then gives the non-negative remainder. To be universally useful you either need an if-branching or another remainder operation for the case where `a%b` already was non-negative.

Comment: If it is known that |a| ≤ A=kb ≤ maxint/2 for some k, (a + A) % b can do as well.

Comment: Yes, if enough remainders get computed that the operations `q=maxint/(2*b); A=q*b` are a small constant cost.

Comment: In practical situations, `A` can sometimes be hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator does not implement a true modulo. In fact,

```
a ≥ 0 -> a % b = a mod b
a < 0 -> a % b = - ((-a) mod b)
```

Now,

```
a                 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4
a mod 4            0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0
a % 4              0 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  0
(a % 4 + 4) % b    0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0
```

Unfortunately, this doubles the cost of the modulo, which is significant.